# Navigation bar won't move

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line my navigation on the right side of the header and I want it to align with my name (Jae Hong). Here is my HTML

```css
  .banner {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 90px;
}

.banner h1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #000;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1> Jae Hong</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#website" class="active"><b><u>Home</b></u></a></li>
      <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Not sure why the navigation is on the very bottom of the banner box

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `position: absolute;` to the `h1`

```css
.banner {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 90px;
}

.banner h1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1> Jae Hong</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#website" class="active">
          <!-- here was something wrong -->
          <!-- with opening/closing tags -->
              <b>
                  <u>Home</u>
              </b>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `h1` and `ul` elements are both `block` elements by default so the will take up 100% the width of its parent container. That is why you are seeing your nav on on a separate line.

One option would be to change your `ul` to `display: inline` and then add `float: right` to push it to the end of the container. You can then add `float: left` to the h1 element to push it to the left.

```css
.banner {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 90px;
}

.banner h1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1> Jae Hong</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#website" class="active"><b><u>Home</b></u></a></li>
      <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

This is just 1 example. Another option would be to use `display: flex` for your header and then align your content accordingly.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you. I am still having trouble understanding this display property. I think I understand block and inline, but I wasn't even aware that there was a flex option. Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: @JayHong `display: flex` refers to the Flexbox property of an element, which was a new design layout that came to CSS3. You can read more about it at this W3 Link - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp - I highly suggest looking into using it as it can help with responsive layouts and allow for easier manipulation of elements since you can avoid the `float` property and the need to `clear` the `float`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .banner {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 90px;
   display: inline-block;
}

.banner h1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #000;
 
}

  nav{

 display: inline-block;
 }

  nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  list-style-type: none;
```

```html
<div class="banner">
 <h1> Jae Hong</h1>
</div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#website" class="active"><b><u>Home</b></u></a></li>
      <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Check this code. You have the nav inside your banner div. The h1 tag and nav tag are also block elements. Let me know if you need more clear explanation.

And FYI Check bootstrap. It is easy to learn and will save loads of time once you get used to it. W3schools has the beginner tutorials. I would suggest you to strat with w3schools and move on to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using flexbox. See below code(read comments in code). You can also read more about "Flexbox".

```css
.banner {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 90px;
  display: flex;;/**Added**/
  align-items: center;;/**Added**/
  flex-wrap: wrap;/**Added**/
}

.banner h1 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 170px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  color: #000;
}
/**Added**/
nav {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;/**You can remove if you like**/
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1> Jae Hong</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#website" class="active"><b><u>Home</b></u></a></li>
      <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```